# How to use external memory on a microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller

In the past, I've worked a lot with 8 bit AVR's and MSP430's where both the RAM and flash were stored on the chip directly.  When you compile and download your program, it sort of "just works" and you don't need to worry about where and how variables are actually stored.

Now I'm starting a project where I'd like to be able to add some external memory to a microcontroller (a TI Stellaris LM3S9D92 if that matters) but I'm not entirely sure how you get your code to use the external RAM.  I can see how you configure the external bus pretty much like any other peripheral but what confuses me is how the processor keeps track of when to talk to the external memory and when to talk to the internal one.

From what I can tell, the external RAM is mapped to the same address space as the internal SRAM (internal starts at 0x20000000 and external starts at 0x60000000).  Does that mean if I wrote something like this:

```
int* x= 0x20000000;
int* y= 0x60000000;
```

Would x and y would point to the first 4 bytes (assuming 32 bit ints) of internal and external RAM respectively?  If so, what if I did something like this:

```
int x[999999999999]; //some super big array that uses all the internal ram
int y[999999999999]; //this would have to be in external ram or it wouldn't fit
```

I imagine that I'd need to tell *something* about the boundaries of where each type of memory is or do I have it all wrong and the hardware figures it out on its own?  Do linker scripts deal with this?  I know they have something to do with memory mapping but I don't know what exactly.  After reading about how to set up an ARM cross compiler I get the feeling that something like winavr (avr-gcc) was doing a lot of stuff like this for me behind the scenes so I wouldn't have to deal with it.

Sorry for rambling a bit but I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me if I'm on the right track with this stuff.

**Update**

For any future readers I found this after another few hours of googling http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/index.html.  Combined with answers here it helped me a lot.

Comment: You might want to ask on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. You might also want to check out the [Stellaris data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms257a/spms257a.pdf).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally that is exactly how it works.  You have to properly setup the hardware and/or the hardware may already have things hardcoded at fixed addresses.

You could ask the same question, how does the hardware know that when I write a byte to address 0x21000010 (I just made that up) that that is the uart transmit holding register and that write means I want to send a byte out the uart?   The answer because it is hardcoded in the logic that way.  Or the logic might have an offset, the uart might be able to move it might be at some other control register contents plus 0x10.  change that control register (which itself has some hardcoded address) from 0x21000000, to 0x90000000 and then write to 0x90000010 and another byte goes out the uart.

I would have to look at that particular part, but if it does support external memory, then in theory that is all you have to do know what addresses in the processors address space are mapped to that external memory and reads and writes will cause external memory accesses.

Intel based computers, PC's, tend to like one big flat address space, use the lspci command on your Linux box (if you have one) or some other command if windows or a mac, and you will find that your video card has been given a chunk of address space.  If you get through the protection of the cpu/operating system and were to write to an address in that space it will go right out the processor through the pcie controllers and into the video card, either causing havoc or maybe just changing the color of a pixel.  You have already dealt with this with your avr and msp430s.  Some addresses in the address space are flash, and some are ram, there is some logic outside the cpu core that looks at the cpu cores address bus and makes decisions on where to send that access.  So far that flash bank and ram bank and logic are all self contained within the boundaries of the chip, this is not too far of a stretch beyond that the logic responds to an address, and from that creates an external memory cycle, when it is done or the result comes back on a read it completes the internal memory cycle and you go on to the next thing.

Does that make any sense or am I making it worse?

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me, one thing I still don't quite get: would I need to manually allocate variables in external/internal ram in C?  I wouldn't expect the stack to be smart enough to jump the internal/external boundary but what if I declare a ton of global variables?  Is there a way to say something like "put this variable in internal ram if it fits, otherwise, make it live on the external ram"?

Comment: those kinds of questions are not specific to external memory, you have to manage your memory no matter what platform you are on. You will likely need to take over control of the linker to place whatever it is you wanted to place in that memory.  running on an embedded system you have to manage your stack and heap if you use one to insure neither collides with something.  tons of globals is one safe way to do that but not necessarily memory efficient.

Comment: for gnu/gcc tools there is a linker script either you wrote it or it is buried in the compiler somewhere and a script is chosen based on perhaps the processor or system type you chose.  you can override that though and use your own.  The gnu/gcc linker scripts are configureable and powerful to a point they can be painful to create and use, you can hand tune the location for each file, maybe even down to functions or variables.  Normally you want your stack in the fastest memory.

Comment: I think the linker script is where I was getting stuck before.  I'm pretty sure I understand now how I can put all of my variables in internal ram OR external ram but I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like have the .data section go from 0x100-0x200, then skip to 0x400-0x800 (just making up numbers).  Everything I find seems to indicate that it needs to be contiguous.

Comment: @nightrain: Generally the way this works is you allocate some part of one of the memories for your stack. The stack must be contiguous. If you can change the memory map, so that you can put the external memory so that it is adjacent to internal ram (e.g. internal=0x1000-0x1fff, external=0x2000-0x2fff) then you could possibly allocate all of the memory to your stack (0x1000-0x2fff). The CPU knows which addresses map to which memories, but the code doesn't need to know (and will not know) which variables will be stored in which memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reserved word register to suggest to the compiler that it put that variable into an internal memory location:
    register int iInside;
Use caution; the compiler knows how many bytes of register storage are available, and when all available space is gone it won't matter.

Use register variables only for things that are going to be used very, very frequently, such as counters.

Comment: 'internal RAM' doesn't mean CPU registers. Also OP wants to do the utmost opposite: use external memory (a chip separate from the µC)